# Azure Service Fabric and Newtonsoft.Json compability issues

Tags: json.net, asp.net-web-api2, owin, azure-service-fabric

I've created a new Service Fabric Application to host a WebAPI service using Owin Self-host.

I updated all the nuget packages for the service project to the latest version and now when I try to start the application I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Binding redirects are setup correctly in App.config to redirect to the latest version of Newtonsoft.Json.

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

The reason I need to update to latest version is due to other dependencies to a newer version of Owin and Newtonsoft.Json.

Is this some known limitation of Service Fabric in combination with Owin?

Comment: Azure Service Fabric should not require Newtonsoft be presented. Guess you are using it somewhere inside an OWIN middleware. If you open references of the project that is unable to load the assembly and find there Newtonsoft.Json, what value is set to the Specific Version property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your projects is using a lower version of the Newtonsoft.Json library. To ensure you have the right version in all of your projects (inside the whole solution), right click the solution (within the Solution Explorer window) and select Manage Nuget packages. Since you are in the solution scope, you will see a "Consolidate" tab beside the other usual tabs (Browse, Install, Update). Select the package Newtonsoft.Json, you will see the versions installed in each project. Make sure that each project uses the same version.

Comment: All projects used the same (and latest version) of Newtonsoft.Json. So I had no success with Consolidate. I solved it by removing all contents of my nuget packages folder and restored all packages again.